# WPF ContextMenu: MenuItem Icon visibility binding error

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, contextmenu, visibility

This is the style for my ContextMenu:

```
<Style x:Key="DIOStyle" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding Content,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"/>
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Style="{StaticResource DeleteMenuItemStyle}"/>
                    <!--<MenuItem Header="Normality">
                        <MenuItem Style="{StaticResource NcMenuItemStyle}"/>
                        <MenuItem Style="{StaticResource NaMenuItemStyle}"/>
                    </MenuItem>-->
                    <MenuItem Style="{StaticResource BothContactsMenuItemStyle}"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
...
```

and this is the style for my MenuItem:

```
<Style x:Key="BothContactsMenuItemStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="Both Contacts"/>
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.BothNaNcChangeCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Icon">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Image Style="{StaticResource Tick16Style}" Visibility="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.BothNaNc, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Command binding is working, instead icon visibility binding give me this error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
>   reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor,
>   AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu', AncestorLevel='1''.
>   BindingExpression:Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.BothNaNc; DataItem=null;
>   target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility'
>   (type 'Visibility')

Why?
Please note, this is working:

```
<MenuItem Header="TEST" Visibility="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.BothNaNc, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define the `Image` element as a resource. This should work:

```
<Image x:Key="img" x:Shared="False"
               Style="{StaticResource Tick16Style}"
               Visibility="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.BothNaNc, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=ContextMenu},
                            Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"/>

<Style x:Key="BothContactsMenuItemStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="Both Contacts"/>
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.BothNaNcChangeCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource img}" />
</Style>
```

If you set the `Icon` property to an `Image` element that you define inline in `<Setter.Value>` like you are currently doing, it will inherit the `DataContext` from the parent `Window` or `UserControl` or wherever the `Style` is defined.